# Each automorphism of the matrix algebra is inner.

Tags: matrices, noncommutative-algebra

Exercise I.II.IV in the book *Local Representation Theory* by **J.L.Alperin**:

> Demonstrate that any automorphism of the algebra $M_n(k)$ is inner by using the fact that $M_n(k)$ has a unique simple module.

I want only hints, as this seems elementary. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Hint:An automorphism $\alpha$ of $M_{n}(k)$ preserves the isomorphism type of the unique simple module $V$ for $M,$ so $V$ and $V^{\alpha}$ give equivalent representations of the matrix ring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness: this is a special case of the [Skolem-Noether theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Noether_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for the indication. No wander I thought of the statement as elementary: I learned something before in this direction. But I forgot to refer to this theorem in pondering. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Let me develop the comments of *Geoff Robinson* further into an incomplete answer.
Since $M_n(k)$ has only one irreducible representation $V$, $V^{\alpha}$ and $V$ must be the same representation. Hence the corresponding matrices are conjugate: so $\alpha$ is inner, for $M_n(k)$ is semisimple.
Point out any error which occurs please. Thanks very much.